# Format a laravel route string to be used in Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am passing data from a blade file to a Vue component. I am passing a collection of programs to Vue and in the collection of programs is an array and within the array are attributes. One of the attributes is a `route` attribute. Since the route is coming from Laravel and not vue router, (I am not using vue-router) the route has the blade file extension appended to it as it would be used in a controller when returning a view: so the way the routes are being returned right now in my Vue Component resembles:

```
route: program1.index,
       program2.index
       program3.index
```

In my index.blade.php file I bind the programs and pass it to vue:

```
<programs :programs="{{App\Programs::all()}}">
 </programs>
```

In Programs.vue I loop through the programs with `v-for` and am properly accessing the route like so:

```
   <template>
        <div>
          <a :href="program.route"></a>
        </div>
    </template>
```

I am using this computed property which properly strips off the `.index` from the routes, but when I check the value of `formattedRoutes` in the vue console it is undefined.

```
computed: {
     formattedRoutes() {
      this.programs.filter(obj => {
        return obj.route.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
      });
    }
}
```

This is me calling the computed property in the html:

```
 <template>
    <div>
       <a :href="program.formattedRoutes"></a>
    </div>
 </template>
```

The `program.formattedRoutes` returns `undefined` I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here...

1. Your computed property doesn't return anything
2. Computed properties should be pure functions. They should not manipulate any data, otherwise you can end up in an infinite loop since computed property functions execute when data changes

I would instead create a computed property to return programs with your transformed routes. For example

```js
computed: {
  linkedPrograms: vm => vm.programs.map(program => ({
    ...program,
    route: program.route.replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
  }))
}
```

Now iterate `linkedPrograms` **instead of** `programs` and use the transformed `route` property in your links. For example (and this is purely guess work because you didn't show how you were iterating `programs` in your template)...

```html
<!-- I'm just guessing with the "id" and "name" properties -->
<div v-for="program in linkedPrograms" :key="program.id">
  <a :href="program.route">{{ program.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but the links are appearing in duplicates across the page.

Comment: so it is appearing like this: ```<div><a href="program1">Program1</a></div> <div><a href="program2">Program2</a></div> <div><a href="program3">Program3</a></div>``` just repeating across the page and also spanning multiple rows. So program 1 shows up three times on the page.

Comment: Well, you didn't show how you were iterating `programs` so I had to improvise. Instead of just blindly copy / pasting an answer that clearly says it's guessing some parts, see if you can adapt it to fit what you actually need